# '+' Operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I just started learning about operator overloading and was just playing around with code to learn how it works. So, I wrote a code that adds two characters. Ex: '#' + '%' = 'H' because of ASCII value addition.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Strings {
//everything is public
public:
    char str;
    //empty constructor
    Strings();
    Strings(char);
    //operator takes in an object of Strings
    Strings operator+(Strings);
};

Strings::Strings()
{}

//constructor
Strings::Strings(char a) {
    str = a;
}

//aso is "another string object"
//makes new empty object "brandNew"
//brandNew is the two characters added together
//returns object brandNew
Strings Strings::operator+(Strings aso) {
    Strings brandNew;
    brandNew.str = str + aso.str;
    return brandNew;
}

int main() {
    Strings a('#');
    Strings b('%');
    Strings c;

    //now, we can use + operator to add characters
    c = a + b;
    cout << c.str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What if I wanted to add two strings? If I make the input

```
Strings a("###");
Strings b("%%%");
```

And I want the output to be

```
HHH
```

How would I alter my code to add the two strings? I started with changing all of the *char* type declarations into *string*. I'm thinking I would have to make a for loop inside the operator function to iterate through each character of both inputs while adding them. But, I'm confused on the syntax for it and also confused on how to implement that. Any help and explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: you are asigning to a char a zero terminated char array. you should have a char*str; insted, or a char str[MAX_SIZE];

Comment: How do you want to add the strings? Your inputs are strings and you want a single character out of their addition? `Strings` has only one data member, which is a `char`. If you change it to a `string`, where will you store this addition? Please think before you post.

Comment: I edited the question above. I want the output as a string "HHH"

Comment: I suggest you overload `+=` first.  Your current implementation for `+` isn't going to work at all, as it is basically a recursive definition.  You're defining how to add strings by adding strings.  But there is no code to actually "add" strings, is there?  Overloading `+=` is where you write the code to concatenate the strings, and `+` uses `+=` (and `+` would then look something like your attempt).

Comment: What have you tried so far regarding the Loop which you already know you Need?

Comment: @ss1111  Also, why not first look at an example of a properly coded, but simple, string class?  Hardly any beginner is going to get this correct without a proper example being shown them.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I found no examples that made sense to me about this which is why I turned to stackoverflow!

Comment: @ss1111 -- *I found no examples that made sense to me* --  Well, that may be because your class itself starts off with a very strange requirement, and you're expecting to see an example that shows how to meet these rather unorthodox requirements.  You would be better off writing a legitimate (but simple) string class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you some help declaring the class.

```
class Strings {
private:
    char* str;
    unsigned int length;
    unsigned int size;
public:
    //constructor
    Strings();
    ~Strings();
    Strings(const char*);
    Strings(const Strings&);
    //operator
    Strings operator+(const Strings&);
    Strings operator+(const char*);
    Strings operator=(const Strings&);
    Strings operator=(const char*);
    Strings operator+=(const Strings&);
    Strings operator+=(const char*);
    ///Accessors
    const char* GetStr()const;
    unsigned int GetLength()const;
    unsigned int GetSize()const;
};
```

Comment: You have to implement at least this function to have a basic string class, having care always of the allocated memory, and checking if there is enough space to save any given string